# How can I create a view that lists users who have NOT completed an order?

Tags: views, 6, ubercart

I am helping with a Drupal 6 / Ubercart site that has tons of spam user accounts registered.

I want to create a view that will list spam accounts. My thinking is that users who have registered but never bought anything in Ubercart have a high probability of being spam so I want to create this view. However, I can't figure out how to filter my user view to list only users who have **not** completed an order.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save to anyone else the trouble, [this is the view I created](http://pastebin.com/HhwZZLjR) to achieve the above.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'Spambots';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->core = 6;
$view->api_version = '2';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('relationships', array(
  'uid' => array(
    'label' => 'Order user',
    'required' => 0,
    'id' => 'uid',
    'table' => 'uc_orders',
    'field' => 'uid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'mail' => array(
    'label' => 'E-mail',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'link_to_user' => 'mailto',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'mail',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'mail',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'created' => array(
    'label' => 'Created date',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'date_format' => 'small',
    'custom_date_format' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'created',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'created',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'login' => array(
    'label' => 'Last login',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'date_format' => 'small',
    'custom_date_format' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'login',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'login',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'edit_node' => array(
    'label' => 'Edit link',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'text' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'edit_node',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'edit_node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'delete_node' => array(
    'label' => 'Delete link',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'absolute' => 0,
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'rel' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'hide_alter_empty' => 1,
    'text' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'delete_node',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'delete_node',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('sorts', array(
  'uid' => array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'id' => 'uid',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'uid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'order_id' => array(
    'operator' => 'empty',
    'value' => array(
      'value' => '',
      'min' => '',
      'max' => '',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'order_id',
    'table' => 'uc_orders',
    'field' => 'order_id',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'rid' => array(
    'operator' => 'not',
    'value' => array(
      3 => '3',
      6 => '6',
      4 => '4',
      5 => '5',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'rid',
    'table' => 'users_roles',
    'field' => 'rid',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'reduce_duplicates' => 0,
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'role',
  'role' => array(
    3 => 3,
    5 => 5,
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('header', 'The following accounts have no orders associated with them and are not assigned a specific role. Therefore it is safe to assume they are spambots.');
$handler->override_option('header_format', '1');
$handler->override_option('header_empty', 1);
$handler->override_option('use_ajax', TRUE);
$handler->override_option('items_per_page', 20);
$handler->override_option('use_pager', '1');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'table');
$handler->override_option('style_options', array(
  'grouping' => '',
  'override' => 1,
  'sticky' => 0,
  'order' => 'asc',
  'summary' => '',
  'columns' => array(
    'mail' => 'mail',
    'login' => 'login',
    'uid' => 'uid',
    'delete_node' => 'delete_node',
  ),
  'info' => array(
    'mail' => array(
      'sortable' => 0,
      'separator' => '',
    ),
    'login' => array(
      'sortable' => 0,
      'separator' => '',
    ),
    'uid' => array(
      'sortable' => 0,
      'separator' => '',
    ),
    'delete_node' => array(
      'separator' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'default' => '-1',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'spambots');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
```

It will need tweaking to your needs because I've got it set up to filter based on user role too but should give you a good base to start with.

Also the SQL is:

```
SELECT users.uid AS uid, users.mail AS users_mail FROM users users  LEFT JOIN uc_orders uc_orders ON users.uid = uc_orders.uid LEFT JOIN users users_uc_orders ON uc_orders.uid = users_uc_orders.uid LEFT JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid AND (users_roles.rid = 3 OR users_roles.rid = 6 OR users_roles.rid = 4 OR users_roles.rid = 5) WHERE (uc_orders.order_id IS NULL) AND (users_roles.rid IS NULL) ORDER BY uid DESC
```

Comment: I finally got around to using this and it works perfectly, but one thing to note is this view requires that the Ubercart Views module is installed.

Answer (score 1):

first you will have to add a relationship linking ubercart orders to a user, then filter by the order number that is not greater than 0.